# Resize image by mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any jquery or another brand of plugins which can resize image inside div using mouse?
I looked through Jquery drug and drop plugins but haven't found anything suitable yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Answer (score 3):

Very easy to create yourself, without utilizing the whole jQ UI lib. Here's a starter plate:

```
var isDragging = false,
    $img = $('#myImg');

$img.bind('mousedown', function(e){
  isDragging = true;
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('body').bind('mousemove', function(e){
  if(isDragging)
    $img.css({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY });
}).bind('mouseup', function(){
  isDragging = false;
});
```

Comment: its drag example not resize....

Comment: I didn't say it was a resize example... it's a starter plate